# tags: <hr>, <section> not covering the whole html from the content page

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-core, tags

I have been migrating codes from `.NET(webform)` to `.NET Core` :

Within `_Layout.cshtml`, the following tags `<hr>`, `<section>` covers the full `width(e.g. 100%)` of the html as expected.
However, inserting similar tags within the `content` pages such as `Index.cshtml` do not cover the full `width` of webpage, for some reasons.

Even after adding in `Index.cshtml`

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
     //test
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <hr style="width:20000%" />
    </div>
```

one ends up with the horizontal line leading the expecting result from the right end side only, as opposed to the left-hand side, thus leaving me puzzled.

I was expecting to face issues following the code(s) migration on items other than the beforementioned tags. Thus any suggestion would very be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this phenomenon, I think you should take a look at the official documentation on _layout.

Doc:[What is a Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0#what-is-a-layout).

Article:[What are Layout, _ViewStart, RenderBody, and RenderSection in MVC?](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-layout-viewstart-renderbody-and-rendersection/).

> RenderBody() is called to render the content of a child view. Any content on said view that is not in a @section declaration will be rendered by RenderBody(). Using the Layout view above, that means that all content in a child view will be rendered inside the . This allows us to separate layout that is common to all views from layout that is specific to a single view.

If we need some part of the page to change based on which child view the user is on,you can use `RenderSection()`.

In your `_layout`:

```
 @RenderSection("Body", required: false)
```

In your view:

```
@section Body
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <hr style="width:20000%" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks indeed for your helpful feedback.